# vim & csv file: put header info into a new column

Tags: regex, vim, csv, replace, copy-paste

I have a large number of csv files that look like this below:

---

xxxxxxxx
xxxxx
Shipment,YD564n
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxx

1,RR1760
2,HI3503
3,HI4084
4,HI1824

---

I need to make them look like the following:

---

xxxxxxxx
xxxxx
Shipment,YD564n
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxx

YD564n,1,RR1760
YD564n,2,HI3503
YD564n,3,HI4084
YD564n,4,HI1824

---

YD564n is a shipment number and will be different for every csv file. But it always comes right after "Shipment,".

What vim command(s) can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a macro, and applying it over several files.

Here's one example. Type the following in as is:

```
3gg$"ayiw:6,$s/^/<C-R>a/<CR>:w<CR>:bn<CR>
```

Now that looks horrendous. Let me see if I can explain that a bit better.

`3gg$` : Go to the end of the third line.

`"ayiw` : Copy the last word into the register `a`.

`:6,$s/^/<C-R>a/<CR>` : In every line from the 6th onwards, replace at the beginning whatever is in register a.

`:w<CR>:bn<CR>` : Save and go to the next buffer.

Now you can map this to a key, by

```
:nnoremap <C-A> 3gg$"ayiw:6,$s/^/<C-R>a/<CR>:w<CR>:bn<CR>
```

Then if you have say 200 csv files, you open vim as

```
vim *.csv
```

and then

```
200<C-A>
```

Where you type Ctrl-A there, and it should be all done.

That said, I'd definitely be more comfortable doing this in a proper scripting language, it'd be much more straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

In one file type the following in normal mode:

```
qqgg/^Shipment,<CR>ww"ay$}j:.,$s/^/<C-R>a,<CR>q
```

Note that `<CR>` is the ENTER key, and `<C-R>` is CTRL-R.

This will update that file and recrd the commands in register q.

Then in each other file type @q (also in normal mode). (this will play back register q)

Answer (score 2):

This could be done as a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -e' $c = do {local $/; <>};
                ($n) = ($c =~ /Shipment,(\w+)/);
                $c =~ s/^(\d+,)/$n,$1/gm;
                print $c' shipment.csv
```

This will read contents of `shipment.csv` into `$c`, extract the shipment ID into `$n`, and prepend every CSV line with the shipment number. The file will be modified in-place with a backup saved to `shipment.csv.bak`.

To do this from within Vim, adapt it as a filter:

```
:%!perl -e' $c = do {local $/; <>}; ($n) = ($c =~ /Shipment,(\w+)/); $c =~ s/^(\d+,)/$n,$1/gm; print $c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't bash me, but... you could consider: Don't do this in vim!!

This is a classic usage example for scripting languages.
Take a basic python, perl or ruby tutorial. The solution for this would
be in it.

The regex for this might not be too difficult and it *is* doable in vim.
But there are much easier alternatives out there.
And much more flexible ones.

Answer (score 1):

Why vim?

Try this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

input=$1

shipment=`grep Shipment $input|awk -F, '{print $2}'`

mv $input $input.orig

sed -e "s/^\([0-9]\)/$shipment,\1/" $input.orig > $input
```

You could iterate through specific files:

```
for input in *.txt
do
    script.sh $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I also think this isn't well suited for vim, how about in Bash instead?

```
FILENAME='filename.csv' && SHIPMENT=`grep Shipment $FILENAME | sed 's/^Shipment,//'` && cat $FILENAME | sed "s/^[0-9]/$SHIPMENT,&/" > $FILENAME
```